# Precisely formatting a cast list for narrow browser windows

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I need to format a "cast list" (a series of person/role pairs) on a web page in a way that approximates professional-looking results when a line's text is wider than the available space in the browser window. But I'm not sure if I should be looking at CSS flexbox, grid, JavaScript, or something else, or if any of these are even capable of generating anything close to what I want.

Here are some examples of the same cast list, manually formatted for different widths. (I'm using a fixed-width font here to make it easier to show alignment, but would prefer a method that works with variable-width fonts.)

```
Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart ................. Court Composer
Antonio Salieri ........ Assistant to the Court Composer
Tim ... Assistant to the Assistant to the Court Composer
John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt ................. Intern
John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt Jr. ....... Secretary to
                     the Assistant to the Court Composer

Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart ..... Court Composer
Antonio Salieri ..... Assistant to the Court
                                    Composer
Tim ...... Assistant to the Assistant to the
                              Court Composer
John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt ..... Intern
John Jacob Jingleheimer
   Schmidt Jr. ............ Secretary to the
             Assistant to the Court Composer

Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart ... Court       ; not ideal, better to break the longer name
                         Composer
Antonio Salieri ....... Assistant
            to the Court Composer
Tim ............ Assistant to the 
  Assistant to the Court Composer
John Jacob Jingleheimer
   Schmidt ............... Intern
John Jacob Jingleheimer
   Schmidt Jr. ..... Secretary to
             the Assistant to the 
                   Court Composer

Wolfgang Amadeus
   Mozart .... Court Composer
Antonio Salieri ... Assistant
        to the Court Composer
Tim ........ Assistant to the
       Assistant to the Court
                     Composer
John Jacob Jingleheimer
   Schmidt ........... Intern
John Jacob Jingleheimer
   Schmidt Jr. .... Secretary
      to the Assistant to the
               Court Composer
```

One way to express the logic behind this layout scheme might be:

1. For each person/role pair, try to set the text in a single line. If it's too wide for that:
2. Compute the width of the last word in the "person" part, and the first word in the "role" part.
3. Break the "person" part into multiple lines, so that each line is no wider than 70% of the available width, and the last line is no wider than the width of the first word in the "role" part (plus a constant to account for indenting and dots).
4. Break the "role" part into multiple lines, so that each line is no wider than 70% of the available width, and the first line is no wider than the width of the last word in the "person" part (plus a constant).
5. Set the "person" part, with subsequent lines indented.
6. After the final line of the "person" part, set the first line of the "role" part, flush right, filling in the extra space with dots.
7. Set the remaining lines of the "role" part, flush right.

Is it possible to get results like the above, using just CSS? Or is it possible to do this kind of thing in JavaScript, measuring words and manually positioning line breaks? Has anyone done anything similar? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Certainly it's possible but it's generally encouraged to show us what you have tried so far so we don't waste our time repeating your previous efforts. A [mcve] would be appreciated too.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can get almost there with just CSS, there is a need to calculate the indent needed on the second column first line which has to be done by JavaScript.

This snippet has two spans within each of the first column divs containing the text. The first span allows a white background to just the text and the second allows calculation of the end of the actual text. From there the indent required on the first line of the second column can be found.

As the dots are just a visual clue they can be included through a pseudo element, repeated radial gradients making the dots.

```js
function resize() {
  const cast = document.querySelector('.cast');
  const castX = cast.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  const leftCols = document.querySelectorAll('.cast > *:nth-child(odd)');
  leftCols.forEach(leftCol => {
    const lastEl = leftCol.querySelector('*:last-child');
    const x = lastEl.getBoundingClientRect().x + lastEl.getBoundingClientRect().width - castX;
    const rightCol = leftCol.nextElementSibling;
    const indent = x - (cast.getBoundingClientRect().width * 30 / 100);
    rightCol.style.setProperty('--indent', indent + 'px');
  });
}
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
```

```css
.cast {
  width: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  --lineheight: 1.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cast>* {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: var(--lineheight);
}

.cast> :nth-child(odd) {
  text-indent: -2em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  text-align: left;
}

.cast>*> :first-child {
  background: white;
}

.cast> :nth-child(odd) :first-child {
  position: relative;
}

.cast> :nth-child(odd) :first-child::after {
  width: 100vw;
  height: var(--lineheight);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: radial-gradient(gray 0 20%, transparent 20% 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(var(--lineheight) / 2) calc(var(--lineheight) / 2);
  background-position: 0 bottom;
}

.cast> :nth-child(even) {
  --indent: 6em;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  text-indent: var(--indent);
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--lineheight));
}
```

```html
<div class="cast">
  <div><span>Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart</span><span></span></div>
  <div><span>Court Composer</span></div>
  <div><span>Antonio Salieri</span><span></span></div>
  <div><span>Assistant to the Court Composer</span></div>
  <div><span>Tim</span><span></span></div>
  <div><span>Assistant to the Assistant to the Court Composer</span></div>
  <div><span>John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt</span><span></span></div>
  <div><span>Intern</span></div>
  <div><span>John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt Jr.</span><span></span></div>
  <div><span>Secretary to the Assistant to the Court Composer</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I see how to add a little space to the left of the dots, applying   margin-left: 1em to the CSS that makes the background image, but how would I add a similar space to the right of the dots? (I tried adding margin and padding to various elements but got nowhere.) And how can I ensure a minimum width of dots, so the person and role names can never bump into each other? Adding min-width to the span with the dots doesn't help.

Comment: To add a space to the right of the dots perhaps padding-left on the span in the even (righthand) side? I don't like the way I haven't go the dots aligned but that defeated me.

Comment: And yes, there is a hacky flaw in the snippet - I didn't bother to calculate exactly how wide the dotty bit should be for each entry - just shoved in a large number and cut it off with an overflow hidden.  It would be better to actually calculate it. There is a wrinkle which I don't understand though in that the text-align and the system's decision on where to wrap text can somehow clash. I was close to putting in an nbsp at the end of the left hand texts and at the beginning of the right hand texts to stop the bumping up but not upsetting the system's text-align/wrap stuff (hopefully).

Comment: I wasn't able to get padding to add space (text just shifted out of view instead) but adding some nbsp entities produced a space where I wanted, and also ensured a minimum width of dots. The only problem I haven't solved is with backgrounds. My actual background is a yellow pattern, so your "background: white;" doesn't look right. Setting the same background as for the body works, sort of, but it seems like  each run of text uses the upper-left corner of the background pattern, instead of the part "underneath". I guess calculating the dot width is the best fix, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: This is one of the actual pages where I'm using this method: https://www.pghplaywrights.org/bw2022-program/

Comment: Good to see it in use. If we calculated the width of the join better then we wouldn't need that solid background to the text would we?

Comment: You can get half way there by removing the background on the first part as the dashes start offset from the text anyway. So .castlisttable>*> :first-child, .name, .role {
    background: url(https://www.pghplaywrights.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/lighter-Red-and-Cream-Handcrafted-Illustrations-Foliage-Desktop-Wallpaper-2-1.png); becoming .role {
    background: url(https://www.pghplaywrights.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/lighter-Red-and-Cream-Handcrafted-Illustrations-Foliage-Desktop-Wallpaper-2-1.png);